# URL with trailing slash to mod_rewrite isn't working even though I'm using ^([A-Za-z]+)(/.*|$)

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect people from: domain-name.com/fileName OR domain-name.com/fileName/ to domain-name.com/industry-template/industrypages/fileName.php

I'm successfully removing the .php extension and redirecting from domain-name.com/fileName, but whenever I add the trailing slash I just get a blank page (not even an error).

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)(/.*|$) /industry-template/industrypages/$1.php [L]`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this in `.htaccess` or apache `.conf` file? (in any case, can you show the full htaccess/VirtualHost configuration)

Comment: Just make the trailing slash optional - `^([A-Za-z]+)/?$`